# RangeError in List.generate Flutter

Tags: flutter, list

I am using list.generate using a list in flutter , doesn't know what is cause such problem.

my list have only two objects but error says 5 , what should i do now?
`

```
List storyList = [
      {
        "name": "Novac",
        "imageUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/31.jpg",
        "isOnline": true,
        "hasStory": true,
      },
      {
        "name": "Derick",
        "imageUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/81.jpg",
        "isOnline": false,
        "hasStory": false,
      },];`
```

`

```
Row(
                children: List.generate(storyList.length, (index) {
                  return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 80,
                              height: 80,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                                          colors: [
                                            // Color(0xffcc306C),
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 225),
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 48, 48),
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 217, 67)
                                          ],
                                          begin: Alignment.topRight,
                                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                                        ),
                                        // border: Border.all(
                                        //     // color: Color(0xffcc306C),
                                        //     width: 5)
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: 75,
                                          height: 75,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border.all(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  width: 4),
                                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                                    storyList[index]
                                                        ['imageUrl'],
                                                  ),
                                                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                ],
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 75,
                              child: Align(
                                  child: Text(storyList[index]['name'],
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))))
                        ],
                      ));
                }),
              )
            ],
          ))
```

`
**EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS  : The following RangeError was thrown building HomePage(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 5**

Comment: The issue coming from different place, can you include minimal but full snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found , there was another widget that was causing the issue. thanking everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ran this code and it was built successfully with no error.